# Rails inception - how to handle a login session within a login session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, session, authentication

I must build a Rails API, which responds to requests from an iPad app. I have, among other things, a Shop model, a User model and a Product model.

The iPad app works like that - once started, first the shop must log in with an ID and a password. This is done by the shop manager (probably in the morning, at the beginning of the working day or even just once, if they never log out). This happens on multiple iPads. Then, an iPad is given to a customer, who, within the “session” of the shop, logs in as a user. The point of this is, that a user can log in with the same credentials in different shops and depending on this, they can see different products in the iPad app.

So, within a Rails session I need to keep a current_user, but also a current_shop. The question is - how do I implement this?

I was thinking of the following - after the shop manager enters id and password, the API returns some token, which is persisted on the iPad. Then - when the user logs in, this token is sent along with their credentials, so that, at the moment of login I know in which shop the user is and know which products to return in the initial response after login. I also save the shop token in the user’s session.

I would first like to know if my general idea is correct. Also, I would like to know how would you implement it. I was thinking of using Devise for the user and hand-rolled authentication for the shop, but I must figure out how to integrate both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise does allow you to use any model and multiple models in parallel. This allows you to use all the nifty helpers like `current_user` and `authenticate_shop!`.

What devise doesn't bring out of the box is an API authentication mechanism. That you can (and have to) implement [yourself](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6)

Using tokens for each of the shop and user accounts seems straight forward. You can even use the same basic mechanism (maybe via HTTP-Header).

```
before_filter :authenticate_xxx_via_token
def authenticate_xxx_via_token
  xxx_id = params[:xxx_id] || request.headers["X-XXX-ID"]
  xxx_token = params[:auth_token] || request.headers["X-XXX-AUTH-TOKEN"]
  xxx       = xxx_id && Xxx.where(id:xxx_id).first

  if xxx && Devise.secure_compare(xxx.authentication_token, xxx_token)
    sign_in xxx, store: false
  end
end
```

So do this once for each model and you can then protect your controllers/actions via `authenticate_xxx!` and use `current_xxx`.

Finally, don't forget to add SSL to your service or all of this is of little use.

Comment: Just a note, it's still not an application that is authenticating, but 2 humans, you still really want to use username and password here and not an API token, or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to still add a login/logout method that generates/resets/returns the (temporary) token. There is not much advantage to use a token instead of username/password other than you do not have to persist the password on the client, just the token.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you're integrating an API driven application, using devise will be of limited use to you. You *could* do it but I have a feeling it will cause more pain than it is worth.

Use Rails built'in `has_secure_password` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

The simplest possible flow without session tokens would go like this:

1. store manager's username and password into the iPad app (you can send an api call to the host to verify it's OK) and the app stores those values in its process memory (not on the disk!)
2. in subsequent API calls you resend the manager's username and password alongside with the customer's username and password and you verify both in  `before_action` of your base controller

A bit more secure solution would be to use a session token which supports multiple ipads:

1. store manager enters his username and password into the ipad app and ipad app sends a store authentication call, you verify the credentials and return a `SecureRandom.base64` digest and you set `Rails.cache` `shop_owner/#{digest}` key to value of `shop_id` for later retrieval, on the app you are free to put the digest on the disk
2. in every subsequent request the digest is sent alongside the customer credentials, in the `before_action` you check the cache for `shop_owner/#{digest}` and retrieve the store ID from there